# render template via service[Symfony 2]

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I am working on custom bundle in symfony2. I am new in symfony2.
My task is to load a javascript on all pages of website. 
I looked on tutorials and found out it can be done by creating a service.
I created the Service class. It is working fine when i am using simple static functions.
Then , I Created a function for ex-

```
public function test(){



 $sett = json_encode($this->anotherfunction());   //returns array
   return $this->render('mybundle:Default:main.js.twig', array('sett'=>$sett) );  


    }
```

I called this function in controller like

```
$this->get('my_service')->test();
```

I get the error

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in E:\xxampp\htdocs\path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 107
```

Edit:
Services/myservice.php

```
<?php

namespace Neil\myBundle\Services;



use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader;
use Neil\MyBundle\Services;



class myService extends Controller {


    public function getHtmlCode(){

        $sett = json_encode(someArray());
        return $this->render('mybundle:Default:main.js.twig', array('sett'=>$sett) );      //This template loads javascript on page.
     //   return 'ssss';

    }
```

Controller

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{



public function testAction(){

    $myService =  $this->get('my_service')->getHtmlCode();


    return $this->render('mybundle:Default:test.html.twig');

}
```

Comment: looks like your service is not properly registered. Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: when i simply try to  return 'somevalue';  . It works . That means service container working fine. Somehow it is not rendering the template

Comment: Look through the error stack to find the line in your code that triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two reasons which can cause this error in your case:

1. if you look at base `Controller` class implementation it declares `render` method which calls `$this->container->get('templating')` service to generate templates.. I think you should inject ContainerInterface to call templating service or drectly inject tempplating service to your service class..
2. You missed to extend the base Controller class in your controller;

PS:// would be better if you show you service class and controller implementation..

**EDIT**

ok, I don't have any idea how to extend the controller class from service class (i've never tried it:) ), but I don't think this is a good idea. Because they are different things. So, if you need to inject any service to your service class, you need to do this steps: 1.read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html) doc pages; 2. create class and inject services:

```
// in this example we're injecting entity manager service 
class myService {

    private $entityManager;

    // Constructor Injection
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
}
```

1. register it:

(XML example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>    
        <service id="my_service" class="MYSERVICECLASS">
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/> <!-- we are injecting the above entity manager service -->
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

PS:// if you need to see what services available in your system, you can output them by typing `app/console container:debug` (or with specific word, example:  `app/console container:debug | grep templating`) in terminal.

Comment: Updated the question. How to inject ContainerInterface? Sorry i am new in this framework

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try , will get back to you